# In existing PDF i have added Image now i want them to redirect me to browser how can i do that using Java in itext?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I have added image in existing PDF. Now i want them clickable which will redirect me to Browser using Java itext. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably you were prompted by the system to add something else than pure code. That's the way you should ask questions, see [ask] and [mcve]. Posting code only isn't of any help to us. Instead, add text to mention what the code is supposed to be doing, why it doesn't work (list the errors if you get any) and mention what you've already tried to solve this problem yourself. That way, you're more likely to get relevant answers.